# Change image into some div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If i have an img into some div with their id, how can i access to it and change the image?
I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="0" class="container">
                <div class="card"> 
                    <div class="front">
                        <img width="100" height="150" src="img/card-back.gif">
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <img width="100" height="150" src="img/card-back.gif">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And i would change the second img, into class "back", how can i do with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a **logical id** to `.container div` say `div0` and use `.children()` and `.find()` as shown :-

```
var $elem = $('#div0 div.back').children('img');
```

Or

```
var $elem = $('#div0 div.back').find('img');
```

Comment: I have many div element like this, with different id; to access specific div i write this? $('#id.back')? or $('#id  .back')?

Comment: @Juppy..yes you can do this way also or just use id selector only because id's will be unique in a page.

Comment: no only class "container" has id, into this class there are another class, card, front and back; so to access to one of this i must write                            $('#id .nameClass')...it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

for accessing to an the image you can use:

```
var tag  = $("div.back").find("img");
```

and for changing the image of img tag you can use

```
$(tag).attr("src",YOUR_NEW_IMAGE_HERE);
```